# Android RxJava, Non Blocking?

Tags: android, rx-java

It was my understanding that rxjava-android performs operations on a separate thread (when provided the correct Scheduler), leading to non-blocking operations, however a quick and dirty test seems to prove this to be incorrect.

I used the following code snippets and in both, scenarios, the UI was being blocked...

**Snippet 1**

```
Observable observable = Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<Object>() {
  @Override
  public void call(Subscriber<? super Object> subscriber) {
    int i = 0;
    while (i == 0) {}
    subscriber.onCompleted();
  }
});
observable.subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread());
observable.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
observable.subscribe();
```

**Snippet 2**

```
Observable observable = Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<Object>() {
  @Override
  public void call(Subscriber<? super Object> subscriber) {
    SystemClock.sleep(5000);
    subscriber.onCompleted();
  }
});
observable.subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread());
observable.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
observable.subscribe();
```

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The mistake is that you use the wrong `Observable`. The correct code should be:

```
Observable observable = Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<Object>() {
  @Override
  public void call(Subscriber<? super Object> subscriber) {
    int i = 0;
    while (i == 0) {}
    subscriber.onCompleted();
  }
});
observable.subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribe();
```

Both `subscribeOn` and `observeOn` return a new Observable which implements their functions. But the original Observable is not modified. Actually, every operator will always create a new Observable without modifying the original one.

Comment: Exactly, the key is to chain the methods

Comment: What is the analog of "AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()" for desktop environment?

Comment: Do you mean Swing? See https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwing/blob/0.x/src/main/java/rx/schedulers/SwingScheduler.java