# UI blocking occurs in Android despite RxJava

Tags: android, rx-java

I am using RxJava to move network access to a separate thread in Android, but my UI still blocks.

I am not using the wrong observable as shown here: [Android RxJava, Non Blocking?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23447077/android-rxjava-non-blocking)

The codepoints [A], [B] and [C] in below code are passed in the order [A] -> [C] -> [B] so the current thread is processed fine and RxJava calls [C] once it had a result. This is fine.

Also, blocking is much better compared to doing the network call on the UI thread, but I still have minor blocking. The UI stays fluent after the call is made, but if the server does not respond in a matter of milliseconds, it blocks.

```
    private search; // search is an instance variable in the same class

    // [A]

    Observable.just(search.find("something")) // search.find calls the REST endpoint
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Action1<Search>() {

                @Override public void call(Search search) {
                    // further processing // [B]
                }

            }, new Action1<Throwable>() {

                @Override public void call(Throwable throwable) {
                    // error handler
                }

            });

    // [C]
```

Could it be a problem that search is an instance variable in the same class where the Observable uses it, but the endpoint call is performed from a separate library? It shouldn't matter, right?

Am I doing anything bad that I shouldn't be doing?

--

Find looks like this (removed exception handling for brevity):

```
public Search find(String searchtext) {
    setSearchtext(searchtext);
    SearchEndpoint.find(Session.getUser().getId(), searchtext);
    return this;
}
```

SearchEndpoint like this:

```
public static Search find(final Long userId, final String searchtext) throws IOException {
    return ApiService.api().searches().find(userId).setFind(searchtext).execute();
}
```

and makes a call to the generated Google cloud endpoint library.

Comment: Could you post more information about your search.find method? I suppose its return type is Search and it is a simple synchronous method call? In that case just() will call search.find(), block until it returns a value and will then wrap this value in an observable, which will instantly call onNext and then onCompleted. Instead: either use RetroFit, or have a look at Observable.create to correctly wrap your REST call in an Observable... Ask again, if you need more help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<Search>() {

    @Override
    // method signature is from memory - I hope I am correct...
    public void call(Subscriber<? super Search> subscriber) {
        try {
            Search search = search.find("something");
            subscriber.onNext(search);
            subscriber.onCompleted();
        } catch (SomeException e) {
            subscriber.onError(e);
        }
    }
})
// and then continue with your .subscribeOn(...)
```

To clarify, maybe this makes the problem with your code more obvious:

```
Observable.just(search.find("something"))
```

is clearly equivalent to

```
Search search = search.find("something");
Observable.just(search)
```

And this makes it obvious that search.find is executed before we ever hand the control over to rxjava and it is executed on whatever thread you are currently on - then the construction of an Observable from the pre-computed value and the delivery of the value happen on another thread but that does not help you much...

Comment: I started using RxJava yesterday and thought RxJava would execute whatever is behind (just) using reflection. If this is not the case, then your explanation makes perfect sense. Funny though that it helped a bit. [I can't test right now, but I will do later and give you feedback.]

Comment: is there a reason why you redefine the variable search? Search search = search.find("something"); -> The IDE tells me "(search) may not have been defined". If I go search = search.find("something"); the code compiles fine.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a few months old-- but instead of `create`ing an entirely new Observable (which is relatively error-prone), you can use the `map` operator to run the search:

```
String search_input = "something"; // this is where you can specify other search terms
Observable.just(search_input) 
      .map(s -> search.find(s))  // search.find calls the REST endpoint
      .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
      .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
      .subscribe( // your subscriber goes here
```

If not using lambdas, that `map` function should look like:

```
.map(new Func1<String, Search>() {
      @Override          
      public Search call(String s) {
          return search.find(s)
      }
 })
```