# RxJava android - does observer block

Tags: android, observer-pattern, rx-java

Given this simple Observer and subscriber combo which simply observes a file IO and then updates in the subscriber based on the value:

```
Observable.just(preferences.getBoolean(C"vibrate", false))
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())//observe on new thread
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()) //subscribe(listen) on main thread
            .subscribe(new Action1<Boolean>() {
                @Override
                public void call(Boolean shouldVibrate) {
                    if (shouldVibrate)
                        Toast.makeText(context,"i should vibrate now",Toast.SHORT).show();
                }

            });
```

My question is, does the observer block until write is complete ? Even though i specify another thread (IO thread) does this observer still block once called by the subscriber ?

Comment: You're considering `preferences.getBoolean` to be the "file IO" here?

Comment: I think [these](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23447077/android-rxjava-non-blocking?rq=1) [questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25853696/ui-blocking-occurs-in-android-despite-rxjava?lq=1) might help?

Comment: yes its a file IO since it writes to the disk.  It actually is just an example i was doing.

Comment: Thanks for the link. so in my case it would not block since its the same observer im using right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Observer` won't block as your operation be done BEFORE you subscribe to your `Observer` (so, it will just emit your value)

Regarding your code (java 8 style for simplicity) :

```
Observable.just(preferences.getBoolean("vibrate", false))
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())//observe on new thread
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()) 
        .subscribe(shouldVibrate) -> {
                if (shouldVibrate) {
                    Toast.makeText(context,"i should vibrate now",Toast.SHORT).show();
                }
        });
```

You can extract the call as a variable `preferences.getBoolean(C"vibrate", false)` :

```
Boolean vibrate = preferences.getBoolean("vibrate", false);
Observable.just(vibrate)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())//observe on new thread
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()) 
        .subscribe(shouldVibrate) -> {
                if (shouldVibrate) {
                    Toast.makeText(context,"i should vibrate now",Toast.SHORT).show();
                }
        });
```

As you can see, the `vibrate` will be computed before and then the main thread will be blocked.

You should write a "lazy" call to your method using `Observable.create` method

```
Observable.create(sub -> {
              Boolean vibrate = preferences.getBoolean("vibrate", false);
              sub.onNext(vibrate);
              sub.onCompleted();

         })
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())//observe on new thread
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()) 
        .subscribe(shouldVibrate) -> {
                if (shouldVibrate) {
                    Toast.makeText(context,"i should vibrate now",Toast.SHORT).show();
                }
        });
```

With this code, the `Boolean vibrate = preferences.getBoolean("vibrate", false);` will be called only when you'll subscribe to your `Observer`.

(regarding to your if, in your subscriber, you can change it with a `filter`)

```
        Observable.create(sub -> {
              Boolean vibrate = preferences.getBoolean("vibrate", false);
              sub.onNext(vibrate);
              sub.onCompleted();

         })
        .filter((value) -> value)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())//observe on new thread
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()) 
        .subscribe(shouldVibrate) -> {
                    Toast.makeText(context,"i should vibrate now",Toast.SHORT).show();
        });
```